# I needed to make max visit_id based on the date. I tried with this code, the result is 0, even if it contains data on the same date. Please advise

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

Please be upon you. I needed to make max visit_id based on the date. I tried with this code, the result is 0, even if it contains data on the same date. Please advise.

```
int max  = db.Table_KASHF
  .Where(s => s.Kashf_date == Kashf_date.Value )
  .Select(s => s.Visit_ID).DefaultIfEmpty(0)
  .Max ();
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] including all the code and data necessary to reproduce the issue. We can't tell easily if you have an issue in your code, or there simply isn't any matching data in your database.

Comment: This might be a case of a slight millisecond difference between dates. You might consider using something like `.Where(s => s.Kashf_date.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff") == Kashf_date.Value.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff")`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.